# Split page that is larger than A4 with python

Tags: python

I got problem. I receive pdf and some pages there are longer then A4 height. I need to take that page and split data in multiple A4 pages. Like Page Break in data. Where to start with python? Can it be done with PyPDF2?

Tried with python. Couldn't find how to check for raw data height in page.